# Correct answer for this limit?

Tags: calculus, limits, epsilon-delta

So I tutor this student, and we came to the conclusion that the delta needs to be 0.1975, but her TA thinks it should be 0.2025. This was a homework question for her, and she got it wrong because she originally had what I had. Where did I go wrong, and how can you prove it using the epsilon delta proof? Everything I have found, and every attempt at a solution I give says that we were correct...

I found this answer by finding b and c, then finding the distances from x=4. Knowing the nature of $\sqrt{x}$, the shortest distance would need to be delta to avoid being outside the range of epsilon by picking the larger distance. This comes out to the distance from b to 4, which is 0.1975.

I proved this using the standard epsilon delta proof and it worked out. If needed, I can go through my steps here

[image]

Comment: We could tell where you went wrong _only_ if you show how you arrived to the answer.

Comment: you are correct though

Comment: @user58697 apologies! Im not sure where it went...

Comment: IMHO asking students to find the largest possible $\delta$ that still works is pedagogically harming. It reinforces the misguided thinking that proofs about limits are about solving inequalitites as opposed to making possible crudy but sufficient estimates.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen they arent my favorite either, but they are common questions so I have to help when needed

Comment: The TA is wrong.  You are correct, and so is the reason you gave.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen: the question is not asking the *largest* $\delta$, just *some* $\delta$, and is fully right in doing so.

Comment: From the figure, it is obvious that $\delta\le4-b<c-4$.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Looking at the picture, and judging from the fact that they ask for $b$ and $c$ (totally irrelevant pieces of information), I'm hard pressed to think of another motivation. You're right in that it doesn't matter. But I have seen so many generations of calculus students wasting effort on such questions... Anyway, there is no single "correct" answer. Any $\delta\le\min\{4-b,c-4\}$ will do equally well.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen: this is exactly what they mean by "find *a* positive number". Your grumbling is unjustified, you misread the question. And $b,c$ are absolutely relevant as they are upper bounds for $\delta$, without which you would have to answer by trial and error, which would be pedagogically harming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sanity check:

$$\begin{align}|\sqrt{4-0.1975}-2|&=\color{green}{0.05}
\\|\sqrt{4+0.1975}-2|&=\color{green}{0.04878\cdots}
\\|\sqrt{4-0.2025}-2|&=\color{red}{0.06415\cdots}
\\|\sqrt{4+0.2025}-2|&=\color{green}{0.05}\end{align}$$

Answer (score 2):

The TA's answer is clearly incorrect, because if $\delta = 0.2025$, you can choose $x = 3.8$, which satisfies the condition $|x - 4| < \delta$, but not $|\sqrt{x} - 2| < 0.05$.  If the TA cannot accept this simple counterexample, then they are not competent to grade this question.

Answer (score 1):

Your answer is correct!

Note:
$$|x-4|<\delta \Rightarrow 4-\delta <x<4+\delta \Rightarrow \sqrt{4-\delta}<\sqrt{x}<\sqrt{4+\delta}\\
|2-\sqrt{x}|=\big{|}\frac{(2-\sqrt{x})(2+\sqrt{x})}{2+\sqrt{x}}\big{|}=|\frac{4-x}{2+\sqrt{x}}|<\frac{\delta}{2+\sqrt{4-\delta}}=\epsilon=0.05 \Rightarrow \delta=0.1975.$$